How to model log(e^x/(e^y+c)) in cvxpy with respect to DCP rules?
I have this objective function.
Maximize log(e^X/(e^Y+c)) where X and Y are positive Variable vector and c is a constant. CVXPY says it does not follow DCP rules. The following is my code.
P_D = cp.Variable(10,nonneg=True)
P_N = cp.Variable(10,nonneg=True)
c = 0.5

obj = cp.log(cp.multiply(cp.exp(P_D), cp.inv_pos(c + cp.exp(P_N))))
objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(obj))

constraints = [P_D <= p_max, P_D>=0]

problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
problem.solve(solver = cp.MOSEK)

As I know it is concave function. I realized CVXPY knows multiplication and division of two expressions a non-convex expressions. How Can I model this objective function in cvxpy?

Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and just provide code, asap or your question might be kicked out / closed until you update it.

This is x-log(e^y+c) and the second term can be done with the logistic atom.
